# CSS navbar image issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I was just doing some tests with my navbar and when I wanted to put an image right before username, this happend. I don't really know what is the problem, I usually do server-side scripting but not these design. This active class on dropdown menu, as planned, needed to be together with the image, but actually it's only going to the half. If someone can give me example of what things I could put on my CSS file because there lies the problem.
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43WYq.jpg)

```
.navbar-image {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: -19px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.nav-img {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-img" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
          <img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}" class='navbar-image'> 
          {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/posts"><i class='fa fa-btn fa-sticky-note'></i>Posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="/profile"><i class='fa fa-btn fa-user'></i>Profile</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Log out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: can you add your html code as well?

Comment: I added the html code.

Comment: You should try to make a jsfiddle, it's hard to help you with just that. Maybe even a link to your site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
.dropdown, .dropdown-toggle, .dropdown-menu {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-toggle, .dropdown-menu {
    float: right;
}

.navbar-image {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: it helped now. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome! Just a note for the future - when you position something with `fixed` or `absolute`, you take it *out of the flow* from elements positioned with `relative` or `static`. That's why the hover effect didn't apply to the image. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again. I will consider it next time! :D

Answer (score 0):

Here are  the fixes of your menu image:

```
.dropdown { position: relative; }
.navbar-image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    top: 10px; /*** Set value as per your required ***/
    right: 10px; /*** Set value as per your required ***/
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.navbar-image {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
          <img src="//placehold.it/80x80/?text=%20" class='navbar-image'>
          User Name <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="/posts"><i class='fa fa-btn fa-sticky-note'></i>Posts</a></li>
          <li><a href="/profile"><i class='fa fa-btn fa-user'></i>Profile</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This works, but the rest of the navbar gets a bug with the padding, but anyway, I fixed it earlier, thanks for the reply though :)

Comment: @user6106183 Do you mean [the fix like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37774406/6263942)?